# How to request cancelation in InsightsExternalData

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

i  updating Requested Action field to "Process"), no more edits are allowed on the objects.So,how to request cancelation
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is written at the end of the highlighted sentence: "except to request cancelation".

This said, if you look for "Action" a bit down the page, you can find that it can have a value that would do the thing, "Abort", but that is not used yet.

It seems that the documentation lacks consistency regarding the current state of the functionalities.